# Change old commit messages in Git

Tags: git, commit

I have to replace a text with another one in all the git repo commit messages.
It seems to be possible with `git rebase -i ...` that opens a text editor but I have to do it automatically.
Is it doable with some of the git commands or maybe with a Java library?

Comment: I *think* you can do that with `git filter-branch` as you essentially get to execute a script per commit, and can change all the metadata in there. *Think* is the operative word, so I'm leaving this as just a comment.

Comment: If you want to use `rebase` you can do something like `git rebase -i -x "git commit --amend --message yourmessage" refspec`. This will allow you to execute arbitrary commands and change any messages.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yeah. I've used it already. There seems to be a tool that can achieve it by using filter-branch behind the coulisses https://github.com/da-x/git-search-replace
But I've not used it yet.

Comment: Note that in all cases—whether using `git rebase` or `git filter-branch` or any other tool—what you're doing is not *changing* an old commit, but rather, *copying* that old commit to a new (but different and improved) one. To use the new and improved commit easily, you also then copy any and all subsequent commits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git filter-branch` is the tool to use for automatic bulk history rewriting.

Specifically [`--msg-filter`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#Documentation/git-filter-branch.txt---msg-filterltcommandgt):

> --msg-filter 
> This is the filter for rewriting the commit messages. The argument is evaluated in the shell with the original commit message on standard input; its standard output is used as the new commit message.

In your case, a simple `sed` as the command might suffice.